# How to Convert data from Json to timestamp and load it in google firecloud?

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-firestore

```
 r = requests.get('https://www.ercot.com/api/1/services/read/dashboards/todays-outlook.json?_=1645221653127')

loaded=r.json()
loaded
```

[image]

Now I have loaded the data into a google firebase

[image]

The problem is how do I convert the interval and hour ending to the timestamp and load it in google firebase? Also, how can I remove the record id like 0,1,2,3,4 ?

I am looking at something like this as in the below screenshot:-

[image]

Website Link :- https://www.ercot.com/gridmktinfo/dashboards/supplyanddemand

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: you can use standard module `datetime.datetime.strptime()` to parse date and time and later get timestamp. And you can use `datetime.timedelta` to add some value (interval) to `datetime`. And you can use `for`-loop to repeat it for many elements in JSON.

Comment: your links gives me `"This request was blocked by the security rules"`. Probably only you have access.

Comment: Hi Sorry about that. I am new to stack overflow so still exploring.

Comment: I am not very proficient with python programming. If u can share the code I would be glad.

Comment: cred = credentials.Certificate("project.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)